Visible seams when change pose
I have been working on my character model and run into an issue I can't figure out. My character is mesh divided into body parts, which resulted in seams in between the parts. I have applied data transfer from my whole mesh ( vertex data>vertex groups>nearest face interpolated & face corner data>custom normals>nearest face interpolated) and the seams did go away. However, they disappear only when the rig is in rest pose, when I move my rig, the seam becomes visible again. Thank you for any suggestions.



make sure that the overlapping vertices are assigned to the exact same vertex groups with the same weight

I have double-checked all vertices on the neck seam and they appear to have the same vertex groups assigned and all weight values between overlapping vertices were the same as well

could you please share your file? remove all the parts of the mesh that are not necessary...

ofc, I will be grateful if you can tell me what am I missing. Here is the file

is there a reason why you need to keep the body and head separate?

yeah, I am trying to learn how modular characters work

Jakemoyo's solution works but it means that you need to keep the modifier unapplied, i don't think that you can fix your problem otherwise

It's gonna be a bit of a pain in the butt to sort out with all the different pieces you have, but not too bad. Just add your problem verts to a vertex group, probably a good idea to label it accordingly cause you might have to do this  with every border edge with a different modifier targeting each relevant piece.

Then add a Data Transfer modifier, and set it to transfer Vertex Group weights (which should help with any gaps/separation issues) and also transfer Face Corners (to fix the shading seam). Set the target at whatever mesh it should be copying (the head in this case).

Before:

After:

